# Why log4j2 still using old version in maven pom

Tags: maven, log4j2

I follow [this](https://spring.io/blog/2021/12/10/log4j2-vulnerability-and-spring-boot) example to upgrade log4j2 but in dependency tree there is still old version. Why ?

```
<properties>
    <log4j2.version>2.16.0</log4j2.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

dependency:

```
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO]    +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.31:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.14.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.14.1:compile
[INFO]    \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.31:compile
```

Comment: From your dependency tree it seems that you are using Logback, not Log4J. Is that correct? Also from your linked documentation: `The log4j-to-slf4j and log4j-api jars that we include in spring-boot-starter-logging cannot be exploited on their own`.

Comment: I know it is not exploit but try to explain to boss... and yes I am using spring-boot-starter-logging which use just api and log4j-to-slf4j  which I want to upgrade to version 2.16.0

Comment: First you have to define the log4j bom before spring boot bom...second it looks like you don't even use log4j-core ... instead you are using logback...so why? If you boss does not understand he might not be the right person to order what should being done...

Comment: question is why it use still old version. I want to use version 2.16.0 not 2.14.1. hm interesting I did not know about dependency order. thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

You will need to include the log4j-bom first, and then the spring bom:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```